# dbeaver - Open with Excel option

Tags: dbeaver

I am using the Community edition 21.3.0. In the Results window, when I right click, then go to "Open With" the only option is "Web browser". Is there a way to add "Excel"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select all the results, then copy with CTRL+C, go to excel and paste your results.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but there are two issues...  1) a previous edition had the Open With Excel option.  But when I updated to the new edition, it seemed like that option is now gone and 2) copying and pasting would not be okay when a value in the output has a leading zero - when pasting into Excel, the leading zero disappears.   So I am wondering if there is some way to get the Open With Excel option back - I've looked in Preferences, but didn't see it, but maybe I just missed it.  Again, thanks for responding! Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can install Office Extension in DBeaver: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Optional-extensions#office-integration

[image: Excel button in DBeaver]

Comment: I installed plugin, I have this error: Can't instantiate data exporter Class 'org.jkiss.dbeaver.data.office.export.DataExporterXLSX' not found Is there a workaround?

Comment: What DBeaver version do you use? What OS?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 20.04 os and DBeaver 22.0.2.202204041542